# Сравнение времени Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть json за которым мы постоянно ходим и в который постоянно добавляется что-то новое сверху в [0]. time.sleep(30) У каждого из постов есть время published. Задача - вывести на печать каждый новый пост без повторений старых и не дублируя ни один.

В лоб:

```
date1 = data1['results'][0]['published']
time.sleep(30)
date2 = data2['results'][0]['published']
if date1 > date2
print(date1)
if date1 < date2
print(date2)
```

но это работает если дата2 стала старше в момент похода именно за ней, а что делать если дата1 обновилась до похода за дата2...

Comment: Во-первых, у постов должен быть какой-нибудь id и правильнее проверять уникальность по id, а не сравнивать даты. Во-вторых, в каком именно формате дата-то?

Comment: 2019-12-02T12:00:00Z

Comment: Фразу «дата1 обновилась до похода за дата2» я не совсем понял, это как?

Comment: начинаем цикл, идем за дата1, через 30 секунд идем за дата 2. они одинаковые. запускаем цикл снова, идем за дата 1 и дата2, а они обе другие уже пока мы ходили (сервер отдает не чаще 30 секунд)

Comment: Вы что-то странное творите, зачем эти дата1 и дата2, почему бы просто не хранить предыдущую дату (30 секунд назад) и не сравнивать её с текущей скачанной датой?

Comment: как вариант. спасибо